# Codeigniter session is not working on PHP 7.3.0

Tags: rest, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter version 3.1.10 on PHP 7.3.0.when i am setting and retriving sesssion from same method means it will work. when try to accesss session from different method from the same controller and
from different controller will not work.

```
 this is how i set the session
 $this->session->set_userdata('somename','10');  

  get session
     $this->session->userdata('somename');
```

Comment: Did you load the `session` library in the `controller`?

Comment: load the session in autolad.php                                                                                                $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','email');

Comment: What are your session and cookie `$config` settings?